# App launchimage not updated

Tags: ios, launchimage

As before I used LaunchScreen.storyboard as a LaunchImage, in the latest version ,I setup the LaunchImage in Images.xcassets and deleted LaunchScreen.storyboard ,deleted 'Launch Screen File' in 'Targets-General'.
When there is a ealrlier version in device, after updated the lastest app in AppStore,the launch image not update.
Has anyone experienced this before? 
How can I solve this problem

Comment: Did you change the `LaunchScreen` in your project's settings? You need to select `User Images Source` for `Launch Image` option in your project settings.

Comment: I had changed the project's settings, and make sure all settings are correct.

Comment: The matter is when I uninstall the app and install it again, the launch image shows the new one, however when I update the app ,it shows the old one.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Is there any solution to fix it?